# Run a sub query?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have the following query:

```
SELECT, cat_name, cat_id, cat_url_title, cat_image, cat_order
FROM exp_categories 
WHERE parent_id = '1' 
ORDER BY cat_order
```

and 'cat_id' returns the following:

3,4,5,6

Is it possible to run a sub query to check on each loop if the '`cat_id`' that's returned is in the '`parent_id`' column at all? I simply want to return a '0' or '1' or 'y' or 'no'.

Comment: Use a `CASE` statement in order to achieve this.

Comment: Do you want to check if 3,4,5,6 = 1?It will return no for all.

Comment: @Mihai I want to check if any of these 'cat_id' exists in the 'parent_id' column. If so, return a 1 for yes, else 0 for no. I need this happen on each loop, so for example check for 3, then for 4, etc

Comment: Do you want to search in the `parent_id` column of the same row, or parent_id of any other row?

Comment: @Barmar Any row. I just want to know if that specific 'cat_id' exists as a parent anywhere in the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` with `FIND_IN_SET`

```
SELECT a.cat_name, a.cat_id, a.cat_url_title, a.cat_image, a.cat_order,
       MAX(b.parent_id IS NOT NULL) AS cat_in_parent
FROM exp_categories AS a
LEFT JOIN exp_categories AS b ON FIND_IN_SET(b.parent_id, a.cat_id)
GROUP BY a.cat_name
ORDER BY cat_order
```